# About Automatic Release of app on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to automatically release my new app at a set date, but I am a bit unsure if it is enough to just cross in the automatic release button and set a date, or do I also need to press the "Release this Version" button to confirm? I am afraid if I press this button it could mean it will actually release it directly?

[image: screenshot]

Do anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Go To Appstore
2. Select Appstore Tab
3. Select Waiting for Review Tab
4. Scroll Down to Version Release
5. Select Automatically release this version or Manually release this
   version.
6. Finally hit Save Button and It's Done.

Answer (score 0):

I just spoke to an Apple rep about this. She said if you want to automatically release your app, simply set the automatic release date and click `Save`. Don't click `Release this version`, or you will immediately release it to the store.